# Converting pandas series and datetime objects

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, time-series

I have a series of dates with format:

```
df['myDateTimes']
0                       NaT
1       2017-07-23 00:26:50
2                       NaT
3       2017-07-31 04:07:24
```

(where the first number is just the pandas dataframe index)
and I'd like to convert these to Modified Julian Dates

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import julian
import datetime
dtime  = julian.to_jd(df['myDateTimes'], fmt='jd')
```

just gives a

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'month'
```

df['myDateTimes'] is a pandas series and (I think) julian.to_jd needs a datetime.datetime object.

Answer (score 0):

Using `apply` , since you have NaT julian will not expected that , so we filter before we transfer the datetime to julian

```
s[s.notna()].apply(lambda x : julian.to_jd(x,fmt='jd')).reindex(s.index)
Out[139]: 
0             NaN
1    2.457958e+06
2             NaN
3    2.457966e+06
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I get a: "NameError: name 's' is not defined" error. I replace s with df['myDateTimes'] and I get a "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'month'" error.